# Can anyone identify this jet?

Tags: aircraft-identification, fighter, jet

I took the picture in 2011 at McCarran.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

It's an [F-18 Hornet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_F/A-18_Hornet):

[image]
<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_F/A-18_Hornet#/media/File:FA-18C_desert_refueling.jpg)</sup>

Here is a view a little closer to your angle:

[image]
<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_F/A-18_Hornet#/media/File:Finnish_Air_Force_F-18C_RIAT.jpg)</sup>

The one in your picture has extended range fuel tanks under the wings, the one above shows the hardpoint mounting for those fuel tanks.

Comment: Thank you! I was leaning toward F/A-18, but the picture made the tail and wing meld into one another on the left side of the photo which threw me off.